# Is it possible to have a white basemap using d3.js and leaflet?

Tags: d3.js, maps, leaflet

I'm visualizing data on top of a world map using d3 and leaflet. I would like the base map layer to be white, like the one in the following link.

https://resistancemap.cddep.org/AntibioticUse.php

CartoDB doesn't support white base layers though. The one I'm using is positron. Is there some way to make that grey area become white with d3 and leaflet?

[image]

This is the code for adding the layers..

```
var positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
});

var map1 = L.map('map1', {
    center: [19.711510, -4.935242],
    zoom: 2,
    layers: [positron]
});

var baseLayers = {
    "Grayscale (CartoDB)": positron
};

var d3Layer = L.Class.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        return;
    },
    onAdd: function() {
        d3.select("div#map1 .legend").style("display", "block");
        d3.select("div#map1 .regions").style("display", "block");
    },
    onRemove: function() {
        d3.select("div#map1 .regions").style("display", "none");
        d3.select("div#map1 .legend").style("display", "none");
    },
});

var svgLayer = new d3Layer();

var overlays = {
    "GeoJSON Regions": svgLayer
};
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map1);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to try, you can use mapbox-gl.js library, which allows to use personalized vector tiles as basemap, so you can customize any element of the basemap. [Here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-a-custom-style/) you can find some guidelines. Then, it's as easy as passing a property to the map definition:

```
//Mapbox API Token
mapboxgl.accessToken = '{API TOKEN}'

//Setup mapbox-gl map
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/{USERNAME}/{STYLE_ID}', //Copied from Mapbox Studio
    center: [Lng, Lat],
    zoom: 4,  
})
```

Additionaly, you can use D3.js to work with your data layers, as shown in this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/5f4cee0fddc7a64b55a9), you just need to include the `update()` and `projectPoint(lon, lat)` functions after loading data into SVG elements.

I recently managed to configure the vector tiles and it's awesome how smooth they run with pan/zoom/rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't add any `L.TileLayer`s to your map, and use CSS to set its background.